# How do I make multiple buttons and checkboxes moved through css interactable?

Tags: html, css, button, checkbox

I have a page with a checkmark and two buttons. Sometimes when I move them through css I cant interact with them any longer, I have previously solved this through using `z-index: 1;`, like this:

```
<div style="position: relative; bottom: +95; z-index: 1;">
<button name="" value="">Bypass</button>
<button name="open" value="n">Bypass</button>
</div>
```

But when I add a checkbox under these buttons like this:

```
<div style="position: relative; bottom: +115px; font-size: 13px; margin-left: -435px;">1: <input type="checkbox" name="one" value="yes"></div>
```

I can't interact with it.

I have tried adding `z-index: 2;` like this:

```
<div style="position: relative; bottom: +115px; font-size: 13px; margin-left: -435px; z-index: 2;">1: <input type="checkbox" name="one" value="yes"></div>
```

Which makes the checkbox interactable, but it also makes the buttons un-interactable. How can I make both the buttons and the checkbox interactable?

Comment: Use the browser dev tools to figure out what's covering them and fix it.

Comment: Also, use CSS classnames and stylesheets, not inline styles.

Comment: margin-left: -435px it positioning the checkbox 435px outside-left of the screen. What is bottom: +95 ? This code is incomplete. Please create a JSFiddle where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: @SLaks Isn't it the checkbox covering them since I can use the buttons when I remove it?